# CPU cooler for I9 12900

Tags: cooling

I've got all of the parts assembled for my build, sans CPU cooling.  I use PCPartPicker a lot to check compatibilities, and they all seem to flag needing an adapter for Rog Maximus Hero and 12900k combo.  I have a Corsair H115i, water cooling system, but it seems to need longer standoffs.  The standoffs at Corsair are on back order.

I'm looking for a fully compatible, out of the box AIO liquid cooling system for my build.  Any recommendations for something in stock somewhere?

Comment: I read the title and thought: NH-D15 (best air cooler, even outpreforming some AIO coolers). That ain't an option if you want water cooling.

Answer (score 0):

The NH-D15 is an air cooler good enough to cool your Intel Core i9, and Noctua gives free standoffs for LGA1700 at your request when you buy one.

You did ask for an out-of-the-box watercooling solution though, so I also need to add one of those to my answer :). The Be quiet Pure Loop 360mm is watercooling (probably not much better than NH-D15 though) and has the LGA1700 mounting bracket in the box. I don't know if it will  fit in your case though, since it is a 360mm cooler.

If a 360mm radiator won't fit, but a 280mm does, you can get the MSI MAG Core Liquid C280. To see which one is better for your senario though, I need to know which case you have. (second one is probably not much better but it is more expensive)